# Will my iphone insurance company know that I found the old one (which I was supposed to return if found) if I put a new sim card in it?

Tags: iphone, sim

I don't know if this belongs on Ask Different, but I reckoned it does because the core of the question involves the SIM card and apple company data.

My father got traveller's insurance from Asurion for his iPhone before he went on a vacation to France. He lost his iPhone and they replaced it.

All I got from their site:

> You are required to return your damaged or defective device using the prepaid shipping label provided with the replacement device. You will need to return the damaged or defective device within 10-15 days to avoid non-return charges. If the device was lost or stolen, the requirement to return the device does not apply. However, if the lost device is found, you should return it by using the pre-addressed pre-paid return label included with the replacement device.

My phone is currently broken and he suggested that I put my sim card into his old iPhone. **If we do this, will Apple somehow become aware that we didn't turn the phone in even though it was found and notify the insurance company?**

Before you (possibly understandably) flag this as non apple hardware or software related, know that I perused Asurion's website for this information and couldn't find it. I also did thorough research and since the core of the problem comes down to Apple's data and whether they choose to share that with the insurance company, I decided this was the best place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Apple will not tell the insurance company. If the insurance was from Apple (Apple Care) they might know but they won't contact the third party insurance company.

Comment: Will Verizon tell the insurance company?